# Common misspellings: Loosing losing

Tags: phonology, english, orthography

Anecdotally, it seems like one of the more common misspellings on the net (besides then/than, your/you're, etc.), particularly in documents where everything else is spelled correctly, is to use "loosing" in place of "losing."

I have two hypotheses for the relative prevalence of this misspelling:

1. "Lose" and "loose" have similar meanings (unlike, for example, "then" and "than")
2. English phonology might predict that "lose" has a long 'o' like in "hose", while "loose" equates to the 'u' in "moose," which is what spellers might be aiming for. This reasoning despite the strong (and correct) phonological inclination toward an 's' sibilant in "?oose" but 'z' in "?ose".
3. The Black Eyed Peas popularize the variant in some song that I'm not familiar with.

Which hypothesis seems more reasonable? Are there any other pairs like lose/loose? Perhaps in other languages?

I also realize I might just notice this more because I've been paying attention, so maybe I'm just being [over-sensitive](http://www.theonion.com/articles/15-most-common-misspellings,35595/).

Comment: To me the big difference is that lose/loose is mostly by non native speakers and typos whereas then/than is made by native and non native speakers unclear on the difference and your/you're is mostly by native speakers who are bad at spelling or making "thinkos".

Comment: There is a longstanding confusion of /lus/ 'loose' and /luz/ 'lose', along with /lɔs/ 'loss', /lɔst/ 'lost', and /ri'lis/ 'release'. They have been conflated in Germanic languages and dialects for millennia. Check the OED listing for ***lose** [v.1]* for a discussion of the history.

Comment: I always thought that the "confusion" arose from them having a very similar pronunciation.